# How to create keybinding similar to f/F/t/T to go after said char

Tags: vim, neovim

What would be the macro or script to bind, for example, `q` to behave like `t`, but goes after the character, instead of before? For example, if I'm at start position in the string

```
hwllw_world
```

and type `q_`, it would send me on the 3rd `w` (and yes I know I could do `3fw`).

I know how to write a classic macro, but since it requires an input in between the manipulation, I don't know how to handle it.

Maybe there is an easy solution that I have not seen.

Comment: "behave like `t`, but goes after the character, instead of before" with the provided example, that would be `f_<Right>` or `f_l`. Do you *really* need to shave off that extra keystroke?

Comment: Yes, because I remapped `l`, and I do not want to use arrows.

Comment: And you don't want to use your "remapped" `l` either? Also, as-is, this is a possible programming *problem*, not a programming *question*. To become the latter, it would need to include an actual attempt to solve the *problem* programatically.

Comment: I tried writing a lua script where I prompt for a character, then execute the sequence, but then I need to do another extra step (press <CR>).

Comment: Then add that lua script to the question so that people can help you fix it (and remove the now irrelevant `vim` tag).

Comment: this whole process is a useless rabbit hole. You are not using `l` because you remapped it, so you now want to remap `q` too. `q` is already used too, so that will be your next problem. Just remove the map on `l` and map it to something after the leader key -> problem solved. If you really want to go into the wonderland, romainl's comment contains everything you need to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read a character to jump to, you can use the built-in `getchar()` function. That will wait until you press a key and return its numeric code, so you can use `nr2char(` to transform it to a character. Something like this seems to work for me:

```
nnoremap <silent> q :<c-u>call <SID>JumpAfter()<cr>

function s:JumpAfter()
  let char = nr2char(getchar())
  exe 'normal! ' . v:count . 'f' . char . 'l'
endfunction
```

The `<c-u>` makes sure to remove any count prefixed on the mapping (otherwise `3q` will be `3:call ...`), and `v:count` later uses it to jump to the right character.

You'll need to consider failure conditions (what do you want to happen at the end of the line? What if the pressed key is not a character?), but since you mention the problem is the character input, that should be enough of a starting point.

Comment: Thank you! The `getchar` function is indeed exactly what was missing! As for EOL, I in fact use **dahu/vim-fanfingtastic** plugin to use `f` multi-line. I also can handle the failure for non-character. Now I will try to make it repeatable with `;` and `,`.